# Spring Batch - Kafka: KafkaItemReader reads the data ALWAYS from beginning

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-kafka

I'm willing to use Spring Batch for Kafka data consumption. This [spring-tips](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/15/spring-tips-spring-batch-and-apache-kafka) link has a basic example for the same.

Here's my `reader`:

```
  @Bean
  KafkaItemReader<String, String> kafkaItemReader() {
    var props = new Properties();
    props.putAll(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());

    return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, String>()
        .partitions(0)
        .consumerProperties(props)
        .name("customers-reader")
        .saveState(true)
        .topic("test-consumer")
        .build();
  }
```

My `application.properties` file:

```
 spring:
    kafka:
      consumer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        group-id: groupid-Dev
        enable-auto-commit: false
        auto-offset-reset: latest
        auto.commit.interval.ms: 1000
        key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserialize
```

Issue:

- Every time when I launch a job, it seeks 0th Offset. So, I am getting messages from beginning. Is this a bug?
- Why do we need to manually supply partitions to read from? What is it changes in future, wouldn't it affect my code?

Comment: offset is not specified

Comment: Is this happening even when you don't restart the Kafka server?

Answer (score 2):

> Every time when I launch a job, it seeks 0th Offset. So, I am getting messages from beginning. Is this a bug?

No, this is a feature (seriously) :-) The choice of making the kafka item reader reads from the beginning of the partition is to make it consistent with other readers (they all start from the beginning of the datasource). But in the world of Kafka where the offset is a first order concept, we will make the starting offset configurable (we have a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/737) for this). This will be shipped in the upcoming v4.3 [planned for October 2020](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/04/spring-batch-4-0-4-4-1-3-and-4-2-1-available-now).

> Why do we need to manually supply partitions to read from?

Because Spring Batch cannot make the decision of what partition to read from for a given topic name. We are open for suggestions about a reasonable default here.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mahmoud explains in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186355/how-to-commit-the-offsets-when-using-kafkaitemreader-in-spring-batch-job-once-a), the offset is stored in two places: on kafka side with `kafkaConsumer.commitSync()` and on Spring Batch side with `executionContext.put(partition, offset)`.

For example, To make the reader start from the offsets stored in Kafka, you need to set an empty HashMap to a partitionOffset as follows:

```
KafkaItemReader kafkaItemReader = new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, byte[]>()
                    .partitions(0)
                    .consumerProperties(props)
                    .pollTimeout(Duration.of(305000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
                    .name(KAFKA_CONSUMER_NAME)
                    .saveState(true)
                    .topic(topicName)
                    .build();
kafkaItemReader.setPartitionOffsets(new HashMap<>());
```

For other cases like reading the offset from the ExecutionContext, you can check the examples done in the [KafkaItemReaderTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.6/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReaderTests.java#L252) class.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to 1st question:**

You set `enable-auto-commit: false`. In this case you must commit offsets manually or you can set `enable-auto-commit` to true. Otherwise because you don't commit offsets, your current offset will always be zero.

**Answer to 2nd question:**

You don't have to manually supply partitions to read from. You can just set topic to subscribe, then Kafka will assign partitions of this topic to consumers in the same consumer-group evenly.

Comment: 1st Q: I've tried with true, but did not work. So, if I don't supply partition to KafkaItemReaderBuilder, then it should work? I wonder. Probably cz then it will subscribe to topic.

Comment: Nope, spring asserts to provide at least 1 partition. So this is not working.

Comment: @AdiV these are fundamental concepts about Kafka. But I am not familiar with spring-kafka, so I don't know how to apply these with spring-kafka. Sorry for not helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make reader object reference definition out of the read method. this issue face me before and this is the solution

Example code:

```
private KafkaItemReader<String, IRecord> kafkaItemReader;
@Autowired
public EmpolyeeBusinessItemReader(KafkaProperties properties) {
    this.kafkaProperties = properties;
}

@Override
public IRecord read() {
    String methodName = "readEmployeeBusiness";
    LOGGER.traceEntry(methodName);
    if (kafkaItemReader==null) {
        Properties consumerProperties = preparekafkaReader(this.kafkaProperties);
        kafkaItemReader = new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, IRecord>()
                .partitions(1)
                .consumerProperties(consumerProperties)
                .name("employee-business-reader")
                .saveState(true)
                .topic(KafkaConfigurationNames.KafkaTopic.EMP_BUSINESS_PROCESS_TOPIC)
                .build();

        kafkaItemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    }

    return kafkaItemReader.read();

}
```