# Java kafka springbatch not reading messages from last commited offset, running in every 24hrs

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch

I have to read messages from kafka and generate a file in every 24hrs, for this I have written `springboot` java batch using **KafkaItemReader api** which reads the messages and generate a file. But when batch run next time again reads messages from earliest offset, if set the property `gltransaction.reset=latest`, it doesn't not read any messages.
How to make batch read from last commit offset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - Kafka: KafkaItemReader reads the data ALWAYS from beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853711/spring-batch-kafka-kafkaitemreader-reads-the-data-always-from-beginning)

Comment: then what can I use if  I would like to read from kafka topic on daily basis using java, in my case volume of data is very high around 3 million.can you please suggest some thing I am very new kafka and spring

Comment: As mentioned in the answer of the duplicate question above, this will be addressed in the upcoming 4.3 release. In the meantime, you can override `KafkaItemReader#open` and put the offset you want in the execution context before calling `super.open`.

Comment: if I use @kafkaListener instead of KafkaItemReader, then can I read messages from latest offset..? If yes ,then does consumer needs to run for all the time 24*7..?